# fgets() / gets() problem while taking input for N strings. Not taking input at initial position

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, fgets, c-strings, gets

I need to get input for `n` *(user-inputted)* strings. For that I start with defining a two-dimensional array char str[ ][ ].
I used `for` loop getting input from user and have tried `gets()`, `fgets()` both.
In code example although I used gets().
But it is always taking input for n-1 strings, i.e, 1 less than user want to enter.

Upon further checking I found that program is not taking input for *0th string*, i.e., initial string.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
int i, n;

printf("how many string you want to enter: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

char str[n][60];

printf("start entering strings:\n ");

for(i=0;i<n;i++){     
    gets(str[i]);     //have used here fgets() also
}

puts(str[0]);         //no output for Oth string
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
how many string you want to enter:
```

User input - 3

```
how many string you want to enter: 3
start entering strings:
```

Final Output:

```
how many string you want to enter: 3
start entering strings:
 abc
bcd
```

Here program terminates after taking input for only 2 strings and not giving any ouput for `puts(str[0]);`

Although taking input with `scanf()` as `scanf("%s", str[i]);` worked perfectly fine.
 I want to know why using `gets()`, `fgets()` didn't worked.

Comment: To begin with, never ***ever*** use `gets`. It's [a dangerous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) and has therefore even been removed from the C standard.

Comment: have tried `fgets` also. problem is that it is not taking input for str[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with `fgets` (or `gets` for that matter). The problem is your previous call to `scanf`.

When you end the input of the number with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, that <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will be added to the input buffer as a newline. So after `scanf` have read the number, the next character left in the input buffer will be that newline. And that's the first character that `fgets` will read, as an empty line. So it *does* read all the lines, but the first will be considered *empty*.

And that's why you don't *seem* to get any output, because there's no printable characters to print. All you get is an empty line.

Comment: I think, Biggest problem is- I am using wrong text for learning C. :(

Comment: will community help me in choosing right source?

Comment: @Vartika choose the [c] tag and click on "Learn more", there are a lot of tips including resources and books: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info.

Answer (score 4):

You need to consume the remaining buffer leaved by `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
char str[n][60];
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
printf("start entering strings:\n ");
```

You can avoid the ugly flush loop using `fgets` and `strtol` instead of `scanf`:

```
char buf[32];
int i, n = 0;

printf("how many string you want to enter: ");
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    n = (int)strtol(buf, NULL, 10);
}

char str[n][60];
printf("start entering strings:\n ");
```

Comment: I didn't understand.

Comment: You have a nice explanation from @Someprogrammerdude in another answer.

Comment: @asynts, thats why I suggest `fgets` and `strtol`, you can also check if the input is valid using the second parameter, but this is left as an exercise to the OP :)